# How to hint update lock without duplicating stored procedure code

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, deadlock

I've an existing stored procedure SP1 which is simple select from a table. It's being used at multiple places.

Now there is a new code which uses this SP1 along with an update statement in one serializable transaction. I'm seeing deadlock where two transactions are able to acquire read lock on same set of rows and now want to convert that lock to update.

One possible solution is to make this SP1 execute in read committed isolation level. **But I think this is not the right fix,** as there can be lost updates. Another solution is to hint `UPDLOCK` in SP1's select statement. This will resolve the deadlock as whatever transaction acquires that UPDLOCK will only proceed. The other transaction will have to wait for this to commit.

Now adding `UPDLOCK` to this SP1 unnecessarly adds this overhead for other places which call SP1 but don't want `UPDLOCK`. So one might think to duplicate this SP1 and have new `SP1UPDLOCK` which is same as SP1 but with `UPDLOCK`. I don't want this duplication.
So is there any way caller can hint that whatever SP1 returns should be take with UPDLOCK.

Any other better way to solve this type of issue.

I'm using SQL server 2008, C#, .NET 4.

Sample Code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1
    @SomeId int
AS
BEGIN
    Select Foo From Bar Where SomeOne = @SomeId
END

CREATE PROCEDURE SP1UPDLOCK
    @SomeId int
AS
BEGIN
    Select Foo From Bar (UPDLOCK) Where SomeOne = @SomeId
END

CREATE PROCEDURE SP2
    @Foo int
    @SomeId int
AS
BEGIN
    Update Bar
    Set Foo = @foo
    Where SomeOne = @someId
End
```

C# code

```
Using(Transaction t = new Transaction())
{
    result = SP1(someId);
    // some logic here
    if(somecond == true)
    {
        SP2(fooVal, someId);
    }

    t.Commit();
}
```

Comment: you need to show the TSQL, and how you are calling it

Comment: @Mitch will update this in 10mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the calls to SP1 follows by SP2 are atomic, they should be combined in T-SQL.
Or lose the c# transaction. You are prolonging the transaction unnecessarily with roundtrips.

Also, why have UPDLOCK on SP1UPDLOCK but not for SP1? I can't see why. If the problem is lock hints, don't use them. If something is serializable (why?) then again, make it a single atomic call

Note that the default is READ COMMITTED anyway

Finally, do you mean "semaphore" not lock? Using [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) will control flow through the code without using locks on the data

Comment: SP1 is a generic and used a lot of places. If SP1 is used on some other transaction, I don't want to have UPDLOCK there as it will block other read transactions. Also note I want to avoid SP1UPDLOCK proc.

Comment: Use SP3 to wrap SP1 and Sp2 then. Stop using SP1UPDLOCK.

Comment: creating SP3 is not an option. Between SP1 and SP2 there are calls to other SPXs which can't be put under SP3. No I don't mean semaphore. I mean lock the data what I've just read because I may be updating it soon.

Comment: @Ankush: no, you can't do it then.